# Merge b/w two dask data frame giving MemoryError

Tags: python, pandas, merge, parquet, dask

Reading the parquet files

```
df_ss_parq = dd.read_parquet("trainSearchStream.parquet/")
df_ai_parq = dd.read_parquet("AdsInfo.parquet/")
```

Merging the two datasets

```
df_train =(df_ss_parq.merge(df_ai,on="ad_id",how="left")
       ).compute()
```

RAM: 16 GB

I have tried using an index on column "ad_id" which makes it faster but shows the same error.

trainSearchStream size = 17 GB

AdsInfo size = 17 GB

Anybody have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want to fix. From your question it's obvious that even a single data file loaded into memory with pandas or dask will given you MemoryError. How do you expect both of them to fit into memory? So if your objective is to load both files into memory you would need to increase your RAM up to x5-10 times of expected data size. And you don't have to use dask for that by the way.

Comment: How many partitions do you have in each of the data-sets? Be aware that data in memory is usually a good deal larger than on disc, so one partition from each data-set, together with intermediates, can be enough to swamp memory.

Comment: I have tried to increase the partition but it did not work. I know the problem now, I am using .compute which created pandas data-frame bigger than RAM instead I should do more computation before .compute to reduce the size of the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a SQL engine like Impala or Drill to do the join, writing the result out to new Parquet files. The Python data stack is not very well-suited right now for handling joins between large tables in a memory-constrained environment.